# If you deny assertion rights in .NET, does it have any effect?

Tags: c#, .net, cas

In .NET you can deny the security permission 'Assertion' for callers higher on the stack, but would this actually work since Assert() ignores permissions lower on the stack? Since it's the end of the working day I don't presently have time to experiment. Guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers: Appears that it does, in fact, revoke the assertion right for callers higher on the stack. Confusing, eh?

This blog post confirms my findings: http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/08/25/220458.aspx